# Is Samba Domain Controller Machine automatically in domain?

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I have installed Samba on Ubuntu machine and configured as Domain Controller.

In Windows when promoting to DC, Windows Server (for e.g. 2012) is automatically in domain.

How is it works with Samba? When configuring Samba DC on ubuntu machine, mentioned ubuntu is in domain?

Thank you in advance